# Pass param from one header aura component to other aura components on Same page on community

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, platform-event

I am trying to pass one search parameter string from one of the aura component places on header to the other 2 aura components on the content section on community. I believe we cant use application event as we are not in the same container. Also on community I did saw a few posts on stack exchange that EMPI connector is not available for community.

Seems to be that it is possible via comet d only..Although i am not able to find a example for the same.

I have fired event via apex from header aura component like below:

```
 CaseCommunity_FireEvent__e  caseCommunity_FireEventObj = new CaseCommunity_FireEvent__e();
            caseCommunity_FireEventObj.Type__c = 'SearchArticles';
            caseCommunity_FireEventObj.Input_Search_String__c = inputString;
            EventBus.publish(caseCommunity_FireEventObj);
```

Can someone help me with any link on how to suscribe event via cometd or any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is for LWC and I can't say this will definitely work for Aura, but you should be able to make it work there as well I believe. Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.migrate_events) for some hints.

There are other mechanisms available through the [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro) model, but I am not sure this is yet available in Digital Experiences.

With that in mind, until an official page-level pub/sub event model is introduced you can try something like the following:

DOM event listeners must be registered against the `window` object when a component’s `connectedCallback` lifecycle hook is invoked and should be unregistered when the `disconnectedCallback` lifecycle hook is called. A failure to unregister the listeners can result in the LWCs misbehaving on the page since the Lightning Platform re-uses the same DOM document for different record pages of the same type.

The following is an example of how listeners can be registered in such a way as to bind the listener functions to the LWC instance and ensuring that the listeners can later be unregistered:

```
connectedCallback() {
   this._windowEventListeners.error = this.handleErrorEvent.bind(this);
   this._windowEventListeners.ready = this.handleSearchReadyEvent.bind(this);
   this._windowEventListeners.result = this.handleSearchResultsEvent.bind(this);

   // Ensure that the events generated by the LWC are appropriately handled
   window.addEventListener("worker_search_error", this._windowEventListeners.error);
   window.addEventListener("worker_search_ready", this._windowEventListeners.ready);
   window.addEventListener("worker_search_results", this._windowEventListeners.result);
}
```

As can be seen here, the LWC includes a "private" property, `_windowEventListeners`, that holds the listener references. This then allows the unregistering to be performed thus:

```
disconnectedCallback() {
   window.removeEventListener("worker_search_error", this._windowEventListeners.error);
   window.removeEventListener("worker_search_ready", this._windowEventListeners.ready);
   window.removeEventListener("worker_search_results", this._windowEventListeners.result);
}
```

Sending an event to this component is done using code similar to the following:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("worker_search_ready", {
   detail: {
      ...
   }
}));
```

Note that this approach may stop working in future Salesforce releases, but hopefully not before they support a page-wide pub/sub event model in Digital Experiences.